# How can I center the selector-tags?

Tags: html, css

Result as the image below

[image: Result]

I want to center the two `<selector>` in the middle of the table cell. How can I achieve that? Right now the two `<selector>` tags are sticky on the left site.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="n1" oninput="test()" /> <br /><br /> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="result" readonly /><br><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <select id="selector1">
                        <option value="s">Seconds</option>
                        <option value="m">Minutes</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td> <button onclick="myFunction()">Invert</button> </td>
            <td>
                <select id="selector2">
                    <option value="s">Seconds</option>
                    <option value="m">Minutes</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use `tables` for anything other than tabular data. I can't see any good reason for using a `table` for layout here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For aligning `td` center, we have property `align='center'`. Or you can use some class and apply to those `td`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="n1" oninput="test()" /> <br /><br /> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="result" readonly /><br><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                    <select id="selector1">
                        <option value="s">Seconds</option>
                        <option value="m">Minutes</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td> <button onclick="myFunction()">Invert</button> </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select id="selector2">
                    <option value="s">Seconds</option>
                    <option value="m">Minutes</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set center alignment of selector you just have to set text-align: center property to that td tag

```css
.selector-wrapper{
text-align: center;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="n1" oninput="test()" /> <br /><br /> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="result" readonly /><br><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="selector-wrapper">
                    <select id="selector1">
                        <option value="s">Seconds</option>
                        <option value="m">Minutes</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td> <button onclick="myFunction()">Invert</button> </td>
            <td class="selector-wrapper">
                <select id="selector2">
                    <option value="s">Seconds</option>
                    <option value="m">Minutes</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

on the block container that contains #selector1 and #selector2, try:

```
container {
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

*Edit:*

As Heretic Monkey pointed out, what I posted applies to only CSS Grid and Flex containers. So, without changing the td element to a flex container, do this:

```
#selector1 {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}

#selector2 {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks for updating your question so I could see the code. I hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: container {
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

Don't work

Comment: Those properties only work on containers with `display: flex`. Best to wait until the OP has given us code to work off of before answering.

Comment: so please help?